# Log4j-Audit Getting Started fails for Catalog Editor

Tags: log4j, audit

Was doing the Log4J-Audit getting started at https://logging.apache.org/log4j-audit/latest/gettingStarted.html

In the Catalog Editor section found some problems:

1. Download jar url was incorrect, missing "log4j-audit" folder
2. wget url was incorrect, had an extra 1.0.1 folder
3. git remote -v was set to ${remoteRepoUrl} instead of actual http://github.com/etc address.  And the repo was not pulled.   The .git folder was found but the git pull never happened.  I think this might be related to proxy server but not sure if git supports a Variable.

Am I doing it wrong or are the instructions incorrect?
Where can I report such a problem?

In the end, I manually changed the

```
git remote set-url origin http://github.com/etc
```

did a manual git pull, and then the UI finally came up.

Answer (score 1):

So, #1 and #2 are still a problem.

Because I have a corporate proxy server which also requires a user/password

## 3 was solved with adding system env vars like this

java -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxyServer -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -jar log4j-catalog-editor-1.0.1.jar

It does seem that the sun.net.HTTPSClient class which is called, does not mention using Basic Auth so not convinced why it works.

A new thing I found in the Getting Started tutorial is that it's important to change the branch=master in the application.properties.